# PostgreSQL: Set-returning function with single value in plpython3u

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

I want to write a plpython3u function in PostgreSQL that returns a set of texts. I've stumbled across a conundrum that looks strange to me. As per the manual, I can do the following:

```
drop schema if exists X cascade;
create schema X;

create type X.greeting AS (
  who text
  );

create function X.greet( how text )
  returns setof X.greeting language plpython3u as $$
  for who in [ 'World', 'PostgreSQL', 'PL/Python' ]:
    yield ( who, )
  $$;
```

This is a Python function that returns a set of rows with single texts; so much works, and I do get the expected output:

```
select X.greet( 'helo' );

    greet     
--------------
 (World)
 (PostgreSQL)
 (PL/Python)
(3 rows)

select * from X.greet( 'helo' );

    who     
------------
 World
 PostgreSQL
 PL/Python
(3 rows)
```

So far so good. However, I do not want to write a table definition for the purpose, I'd like to use `setof record` instead, like in this example (which happens to use integers, but still):

```
create function X.pairs_of_integers_A( out integer, out integer )
  returns setof record language plpython3u as $$
  return [ ( 12, 24, ), ( 36, 48, ), ( 60, 72, ) ]
  $$;

create function X.pairs_of_integers_B( out integer, out integer )
  returns setof record language plpython3u as $$
  for pair in [ ( 12, 24, ), ( 36, 48, ), ( 60, 72, ) ]:
    yield pair
  $$;

select * from X.pairs_of_integers_A();
select * from X.pairs_of_integers_B();

 column1 | column2 
---------+---------
      12 |      24
      36 |      48
      60 |      72
(3 rows)

 column1 | column2 
---------+---------
      12 |      24
      36 |      48
      60 |      72
(3 rows)
```

Now we come to the interesting part. Generalizing from the above, one or more formulations of the below should be correct: to return a set of single values, either return a list of Python tuples, a list of Python numbers, or else iterate either over tuples with single values or over single values:

```
create function X.single_integers_A( out integer )
  returns setof record language plpython3u as $$
  return [ ( 12, ), ( 36, ), ( 60, ), ]
  $$;

create function X.single_integers_B( out integer )
  returns setof record language plpython3u as $$
  return [ 12, 36, 60, ]
  $$;

create function X.single_integers_C( out integer )
  returns setof record language plpython3u as $$
  for n in [ ( 12, ), ( 36, ), ( 60, ), ]
    yield n
  $$;

create function X.single_integers_D( out integer )
  returns setof record language plpython3u as $$
  for n in [ 12, 36, 60, ]
    yield n
  $$;
```

Turns out **none of the above even compile**, they all cause the SQL parser to throw up with **function result type must be integer because of OUT parameters**. Since I the SQL parser does not look inside Python functions, this leads me to suspect that—

**It is not possible, in PostgreSQL, to define a function with both `returns setof record` and a single `out` parameter; instead, the output type must always be defined as a table (or by similar means)**.

Can anyone please correct me? It would be really annoying if this should turn out to be true. Surely I have made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: yes - function either has out parameters and returns void, or returns something and has no out parameters I think

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: 1) thanks for comments 2) relevant link is https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-data.html#idm46428683116992 3) the docs say, "Set-returning functions with OUT parameters (using RETURNS SETOF record) are also supported."—so yes, out-parameters + returns-setof-record is a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return just set of integers:

```
create or replace function x.single_integers()
returns setof integer language plpython3u as $$
    return [ 12, 36, 60 ]
$$;

select * from x.single_integers();

 single_integers 
-----------------
              12
              36
              60
(3 rows)
```

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) (emphasis added):

> The key point here is that you must write RETURNS SETOF record to indicate that the function returns multiple rows instead of just one. **If there is only one output parameter, write that parameter's type instead of record.**

Comment: I'm relieved I found a lacuna in my understanding of SQL instead of a bug / an oversight / an inconsistency in SQL.